# Why does nested if statement is not working?

Tags: c++

```
case 1:
    {
        insert_menu();
        donor[turn].inputData();
        ::turn++; //accessing global variable
        char c = '\0';
        while (c != '0') {
            cout << "Press 1 to save, 0 to not save: ";
            cin >> c;
            fflush(stdin);
            if (c == '1') {
                cout << "Record saved successfully.";
                cout << "\nWant to insert another record? [y/n]: ";
                char op = '\0';
                cin >> op;
                //fflush(stdin);
                if (op = 'y') {
                    cout << "Enter another record\n\n";
                    donor[::turn].inputData();
                    cout << "Record entered successfully\n";
                    ::turn++; //increment to global variable turn
                } //end scope of nested if
                else {
                    cout << "Press Enter to return to main menu";
                    //fflush(stdin);
                //  getchar();
                    break;
                } //end scope of nested if
            } //end scope of first if
            else {
                ::turn--;
                cout << "Record not saved! You are being redirected to Main Menu" << endl;
                system("pause");
                //break;
            }
        } //end scope of while
    } // end scope of case 1
    break; //exiting case 1
```

I dont know why, when I try to input into nested if else it is skipping it, whether i press y or n, it is giving option to enter input in both conditions. what is the issue?

Comment: PLEASE format that code and ask an actual question

Comment: We need a readable [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a clear problem statement to be able to make sense of this question.

Comment: `if (op = 'y') {` is an assignment. it is always true and sets op to 'y'.

Comment: Try `op == y` maybe?

Comment: use `'1' == c` to avoid such bugs. Or simply remember that `==` is used for comparison

Comment: Ohh, Thanks a lot,  I really dont know how I missed that.

Comment: Your compiler should have issued a warning about this. If it did not you need to turn up the warning level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the line `if (op = 'y') {` is the culprit.

It should be a double equals `if (op == 'y') {`

Comment: Thank you so much, it is fixed now. :)

Comment: That's why we have comments and appropriate close reasons for such kind of questions.

Comment: @ManzarI. You can accept my answer if it helped you

Comment: Sure, I gonna do that. :D In 4 minutes. Thanks again dude